# writing on image capture from camera

Tags: android, bitmap

this is my function that i am trying to write on image
but my log says bitmap (bmp) is null
and the function bmp.getwidth() is on null object reference 
can anyone please me help me out as i am using unscaled bitmap

```
edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {                
            try{
                File file =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/GUI/temp.jpg");
                Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(file);
                BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

                try {
                    if(uri !=null){
                        Log.d("uri2", "onClick: uri is not null");
                        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

                        if(bmp==null){
                            Log.d("bitmap", "onClick: bitmap is null");
                        }
                        else{
                            alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp
                                    .getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
                        }

                        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                        canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
                        paint = new Paint();
                        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
                        matrix = new Matrix();
                        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);
                        img.setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap);
                    }else{
                        Log.d("uri", "onClick: uri is null");
                    }


                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("uri", "onClick: uri is null yes"+e.getMessage());
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you added the permission to your AndroidManifest.xml file which allows you to Read External Storage?

Comment: yes brother but nothing happening

Comment: At the bottom off file you can check file exists use `if(! file.exists()){Log.d("file", "not exist");... } `